# Baby cry noise reduction

Tags: noise-reduction, acoustic

I'm looking for a noise-reduction solution for a residential apartment - the neighbours' baby cries all night and our walls are quite thin...

It must be relatively cheap and easy to (self-)install. But the most important thing is that it will reduce the noise as much as possible.

I found two options - the first is a 0.35in-thick foam-panel with a smooth surface ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C8HH1PLS)) and a density of 12lb/ft3. The second is a 2in-thick foam-panel with a pyramid-shape surface density of 1.25lb/ft3 ([link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005396862364.html)).

Which one do you think is better? Any other recommendations for products or features that the product should have?

Thank you!

Comment: Earplugs, until the tot grows up some.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic. Suggestion - edit and adk what the solution is, rather than what product.

Answer (score 4):

Sound proofing is hard and expensive.

Sorry the easiest solution in your case is going to be ear plugs.  You need a *very* good air seal to cut noise.  After you have the air seal you add density.    95% sound proofing is the same as 50%.  100% is 100% but is very difficult to achieve.

[Sound Absorption Panel](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/sonopan-soundproofing-panels4-foot-x-8-foot-75-inch-thick/1000441119)

[Room sound proofing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCvHilRUP4Q)

Comment: The other thing that can work well is white noise.  Add a fan into the room.